# Pivot table based on programmatically generated recordset lacks refresh button

Tags: excel, vba, refresh, pivot-table, recordset

Excel 2016.

I have in-memory data that I analyze in a Pivot table by setting the Pivot cache to a programmatically created recordset. This works great! The only thing missing is that the refresh option you normally get in the context menu when right-clicking on the Pivot table is grayed out. Apart from this little annoyance, all functionality of a Pivot table is there.

Today, I solve the refresh issue by adding a "Refresh Pivot Table" command to a custom menu for my Excel Add-In. It works, but I don't think it's the proper way of doing it. Refreshing the Pivot Table should be done through the regular "Refresh" command in the context menu.

My questions are:
1) How do I enable the context menu refresh command for a Pivot table when using a programmatically generated recordset?
2) How do I capture the refresh event that would result from selecting the Refresh command?

To give you some more details:

The recordset is created by code similar to this (shortened for convenience)

```
Public Function GetAllDataAsRecordSet() As Recordset

    Dim record As CSummaryDatabaseRecord
    Dim rst As Recordset

    'Create the recordset
    Set rst = New Recordset

    'Prepare fields
    With rst.fields
        .Append "Type", adVarChar, 25
        .Append "Project Number", adInteger
        'More fields here in the real application
    End With

    'Open the recordset for data insertion
    rst.Open

    'Get the data as a collection and create one record for each item in the collection
    For Each record In GetAllData()
        rst.AddNew
        With record
            rst.fields("Type") = .tag
            rst.fields("Project Number") = .ProjectNumber
            'More data here in the real application
        End With
    Next 'record

    Set GetAllDataAsRecordSet = rst

End Function
```

The pivot cache is updated and refreshed by the code below which calls the above class method

```
Set pivot.PivotCache.Recordset = allocationDB.GetAllDataAsRecordSet
pivot.PivotCache.Refresh
```

where the variable "pivot" references the Pivot table in question.

The Pivot cache and Pivot table was originally created with the code below, but once in place, only the recordset of the cache is updated according to the snippet above.

```
Set mainCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlExternal)
Set mainCache.Recordset = allocationDB.GetAllDataAsRecordSet
mainCache.CreatePivotTable Range("A4"), "MainPivot"
```

All-in-all, it works great except for the annoying lack of the Pivot table context menu "Refresh" option being grayed out.

Any help is highly appreciated.

PerE

Comment: It makes sense to me that there's no Refresh button for this pivot table: how would the "built in" refresh function know what to do to recreate the table?

Comment: God point, but that's the reason why I want to capture the refresh event (if there is such a thing). If it is possible to register an event listener to the pivot table (or pivot cache), that could be the way to handle this. Again, not sure how to do it, or if it is possible at all. Thanks!